# What is the best approach to handle common entities in a Webservice

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, asp.net-web-api, architecture

Simple scenario. User/Subscription a subscription has 0-N users and vice versa.

UserService:

```
Users/GetUserSubscriptions(userId) : List<Subscriptions>
Users/GetUsers() : List<Users>
```

SubscriptionService:

```
Subscriptions/GetSubscriptionsUser(subscriptionId) : List<Users>
Subscriptions/GetSubscriptions() : List<Subscriptions>
```

When adding these service references to a project you get for example
SubscriptionService.Subscriptions and UserService.Subscriptions - the same applies for Users

But users are common entities. What is the best approach for this?

Intuitively I want the same class but maybe that would be overengineering?

If I were to make into one type how would that be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

When you started to design this application, you obviously felt the need to split Users and Subscriptions into two different services. You didn't have to. You could have made Subscriptions a property of users or vice versa, but you did neither; you split them up.

What led you to make this design choice was probably correct - you wanted to be able to think about your system as composed of different services, and to be able to make changes to, say, Users, without affecting Subscriptions. These are good things.

However, you have then prevented this from working by the way you have designed your service operations. You have operations belonging to one domain entity returning the other entity. Once you do this, you are actually undoing all the work you put into splitting them up in the first place.

I would suggest reimplementing your service operations to look like the following:

```
Users/GetUsers() : List<Users>
Users/GetUsersBySubscriptionId(int subscriptionId) : List<Users>

Subscriptions/GetSubscriptions() : List<Subscriptions>
Subscriptions/GetSubscriptionsByUserId(int userId) : List<Subscriptions>
```

This way the Users service will only return users, and the Subscriptions service will only return subscription. This allows a consumer of these operations to also handle Users and Subscriptions separately.

Comment: Thanks, it's a side project to learn so your input is really valuable. A simple CRUD and then let the client handle any dependent logic between the 2. Very useful indeed, that's the micro service upside. You can change one without the other but I can definitely see downsides as well

Comment: tom redfern got me thinking. How I would go about making this CRUD but keep the relationship intact, i.e. a users<->subscriptions. If I delete a user I also want to delete the subscription. This lead me to start looking at NServiceBus. Thought in progress and thanks again Tom!

Comment: @TomasHesse glad to have helped!